# Weak convergence of measures and Regularized optimal transport

Tags: probability, probability-theory, machine-learning, optimal-transport

Let W_p be the Wasserstein metric on the space of probability measures on $\mathcal{X}$, a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. I know that $\mu_k \rightarrow \mu$ (under weak convergence of measures) iff $W_p(\mu_k, \mu) \rightarrow 0$. Now instead of working with $W_p$, I am using the entropic regularized version of $W_p$, call it $W_{p, \lambda}$ as introduced in https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2013/file/af21d0c97db2e27e13572cbf59eb343d-Paper.pdf. Due to some pathological properties of $W_{p, \lambda}$, let us assume that the sequence $\mu_k$ is not constant and also the number of samples drawn from our measures are arbitrarily large. Then my question is: Is it still true that
$\mu_k \rightarrow \mu$ iff $W_{p, \lambda}(\mu_k, \mu) \rightarrow 0$

Comment: I don't see where Cuturi introduces $W_{p, \lambda},$ but as a general rule of thumb, you should be able to see that the regularized distance between two measures should be less than or equal to the non-regularized one. And, hence at least one direction in your claim should be true. On the other hand, if $\mu_k$ is converging weakly to some $\mu$ that is very sparse, then $W_{p, \lambda}(\mu_k, \mu)$ will not converge to zero.

Comment: @WhoKnowsWho Thank you for your reply. Sinkhorn distance is Definition 1 in page 3 in Cuturi's paper posted above. And can please explain what you mean $\mu$ that is very sparse? Thank you once again.

Comment: I'll try to work it out later, but I would say that the implication is true, since the regularized Wasserstein is smaller than the not regularized. But I would guess that the regularized Wasserstein going to zero does not imply the weak convergence of measures.

Comment: @DaviBarreira Ok. Thank you so much.

Comment: I haven't been able to figure it out. My guess is still the one above. But I cannot prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I’ve found the answer. [This article by Feydey et al][1] proves that for a compact metric space $X$, and a Lipschitz cost $c$. Then the Sinkhorn Divergence does metrize the weak convergence, i.e $\tilde W_{p,\epsilon}(\mu_n,\mu)\to 0 \iff \mu_n \rightharpoonup \mu$.

Just note that the Sinkhorn divergence is an unbiased version of the regularized cost, where:

$$
\tilde W_{p,\epsilon}(\alpha, \beta)^p =
2W_{p,\epsilon}(\alpha,\beta) -W_{p,\epsilon}(\alpha,\alpha)-W_{p,\epsilon}(\beta,\beta)
$$
[1]: https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01898858/document

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: No problem. I was also curious.